# Buffer amplifier

Tags: amplifier, buffer

I have a buffer amplifier that is single supply 0-10v 
Lets say I give it an input (sine wave 0-10v Vpk-pk) and added a dc level-shifter to shift the input signal up by 0.5v (0.5v-10.5v sine wave Vpk-pk) then the output would be limited to the power supply that is 10v and obviously some clipping would occur. If I added a level-shifter at the output of the buffer with the same level shifter to shift the signal by 0.5v down, would the output be a clipped signal with its voltage level shifted?

Sorry for the long question, I'm a little confused with level-shifters

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first buffer outputs a clipped signal between 0.5 - 10 V losing some data by clipping it, which is shifted down to 0 -  9.5 V, still being clipped. The second buffer doesn't modify this in anyway, so to answer your question: the output would still be clipped.

Remember, voltages are only potential difference. Amplifiers reference their input signals to their ground and power supplies, so in order to prevent clipping, you could shift the first buffer's ground and voltage supply up by 0.5 V. I dont see any use for that though..

**Edit:**
I assume you have 10.5V < power supply available for your lever shifter for them to work. Depending what are the power supplies for the buffer amplifiers, they just might pass the 10.5 V without clipping the signals even though datasheet says otherwise.